# client object model add content type to list

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, sharepoint-clientobject

I have created an SP.List item "lst".
I also:

```
lst.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
lst.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have searched the AvailableContentTypes and found the one I want to add to lst.
I then:

```
SP.ContentTypeCollection lstTypeCollection = lst.ContentTypes;
```

... now I'm stuck.
       the `lstTypeCollection.Add()` wants a `ContentTypeCreationInformation` object
    at that point I'm wandering in the dark.

Can you shed light?  Thanks in Advance  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [ContentTypeCollection.AddExistingContentType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttypecollection.addexistingcontenttype%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to add an existing content type to the list.

### Example

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

var contentType = context.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0120"); //get Folder content type
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(contentType);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Great. Thanks Vadim.